# DLL design : the DLL needs to access some of the application functions/data

Tags: c++, c, visual-c++, dll

I have a DLL with a bunch of functions. So far, so good, that's what DLL are for.
But, some functions in my DLL need to call functions (or access data) from the application which loaded the DLL.

**App.exe :**

```
std::vector<SomeClass> objectsList;
bool foo(void)
{
    ...
}
LoadLibrary( "something.dll" );
```

**something.dll :**

```
__declspec(dllexport) void someFunction(void)
{
    if ( foo() )
    {
        objectsList[2].someAttr = 1;
    }
}
```

For what I know, my DLL code in not correct because the DLL cannot know `foo` or `objectsList` at linking. So, the only way I see is :

**something.dll :**

```
typedef bool fooType(void);
fooType* pFooFunc;
__declspec(dllexport) void setFoo(fooType* fooPtr)
{
    pFooFunc = fooPtr;
}
__declspec(dllexport) void someFunction(void)
{
    if ( (*pFooFunc)() )
    {
        ... _same thing for objectsList_    
    }
}
```

**App.exe :**

```
LoadLibrary( "something.dll" );  
setFoo = GetProcAddress(...);
setFoo(&foo);
```

Am I right or is there a more elegant way to do that kind of stuff ?
Some solutions here : [a DLL need to access symbols of its application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4429141/a-dll-need-to-access-symbols-of-its-application)
But I am still interested in any discussion about this kind of design.

Thanks

Comment: Bleh why are you using dynamic loading? Thats ugly and not portable. Boo.

Comment: Needed for my project : I have embedded Wekbit/V8 to create a sort of AIR environment. I can create browser windows, and dynamically add new Javascript functions to these windows. The JS functions are wrapped in DLL. It allows my app do add/update JS functions on the fly.

Comment: Dynamic loading enables loose coupling and allows component based design, which leads to overall a better design of the application… Furthermore you can update parts of the program without having to redistribute the whole binaries…

Comment: @MFH : Exactly, it allows me to have an application which can auto-update parts of itself without updating the whole application.

Answer (score 2):

There are two common solutions: the first is for the DLL to use
some sort of callback; the second is to put the functions and
data shared between the root and the DLL(s) into a separate DLL
of its own.

Answer (score 1):

Generally you'd pass a pointer to an object with virtual functions.  That way you have object-oriented design and callbacks, with a single function call instead of one per exported function.

Answer (score 0):

In general, a callback *is* an elegant solution.

But it sounds like your DLL is relying on the existence and behaviour of one particular, specific function.  If that is the case, then maybe you need to think about whether you have the correct split between your application and your library.  Is your library going to be used by more than one application?  If yes, then how is this `foo()` business going to work?  If no, then why is it a DLL?

Answer (score 0):

That's a classic design pattern for a callback function.

As long as you document that consumer of your library needs to set a callback and what that callback function is supposed to do, this is fine.

Answer (score 0):

Actually a callback is the best way of doing this -> obviously as Oli mentioned a DLL depending on an external implementation may be a sign of a flawed design.

Personally I'd try to have my DLL depend on no external functions -> apart maybe from a callback to register at the executeable…